# PHP regex to include everything before and after a domain name

Tags: php, regex, referrer

Say I have a referrer that is http://dwz07.foo.net/Player.aspx?All&PID=4321&UID=359010016&STime=921596&SToken=5c93210bdb17ab2c930a1e365b8b05a8e6aca013

What would be the proper regex to include everything before and after foo.net?  Like, I want to include every subdomain and everything after foo.net/

The best I can come up with:

^([^.]+).foo.net$

But that doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'http://dwz07.foo.net/Player.aspx?All&PID=4321&UID=359010016&STime=921596&SToken=5c93210bdb17ab2c930a1e365b8b05a8e6aca013';
$pattern = '/^(.*)(?:\.foo.net.*)/';
$replacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` anchors the regex to the *end* of the string, so it would only match a URL which ended with `.net`.

Your URL doesn't finish with `.net`, it has a `/` after: just remove the `$` to fix that.